# InvalidCastException al aplicar .ToList() con Cast vs. Select en LINQ: Comprendiendo el error y optimizando el código

Tags: c#, linq, unity

Realicé una prueba para medir los tiempos que tomaban ciertas operaciones comparando ciclos con funciones LINQ para ver cómo podía optimizar mi código. Me di cuenta de que la función `.ToList()` es lenta. La cuestión es que, mientras probaba esto, intenté aplicar `.ToList()` a ambos ejemplos que estaba probando.

```
var n = numbs.Select(v => (float)v).ToList();
```

----0----

```
var n2 = numbs2.Cast<float>().ToList();
```

En el primer ejemplo, todo funciona bien, pero en el segundo ejemplo ocurre un error y no entiendo por qué. ¿Podrías ayudarme a entender esto?

```
public List<double> numbs = new List<double>();

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        numbs.Add(Random.Range(0,100000));
    }
    CastTest();
}

private void CastTest()
{
    var numbs2 = new List<double>(numbs);

    var clock = new Stopwatch();
    clock.Start();
    var n = numbs.Select(v => (float)v).ToList();
    clock.Stop();
    Debug.Log(numbs.Count+", " + clock.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    var clock2 = new Stopwatch();
    clock2.Start();
    var n2 = numbs2.Cast<float>().ToList();
    clock2.Stop(); 
    Debug.Log(numbs.Count + ", " + clock2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Error:

```
InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
System.Linq.Enumerable+<CastIterator>d__34`1[TResult].MoveNext () (at <351e49e2a5bf4fd6beabb458ce2255f3>:0)
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]..ctor (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] collection) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) (at <351e49e2a5bf4fd6beabb458ce2255f3>:0)
```

** Editado: Pensé que estaba en StackOverflow en ingles

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si vas a la [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=net-7.0#remarks), se indica que

*(Traducción)*

> Las únicas conversiones de tipo que realiza este método son las
> conversiones de referencia y las conversiones de unboxing

Además

> No se permiten otros tipos de conversión, como aquellos entre
> diferentes tipos numéricos

Con lo último queda claro que no es posible, pero ¿Qué son las conversiones de referencias y unboxing?

#### Conversiones de referencias

[Aquí](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1028-implicit-reference-conversions) una lista de casos, en general se refiere a clases/interfaces derivadas que se convierten en su padre. Es decir tienes la clase `Animal` y una clase derivada `Mamifero`, es posible usar el `IEnumarable.Cast()` para convertir una lista de `Mamifero` en una lista de `Animal`

#### Conversiones Boxing/Unboxing

Básicamente un Boxing es pasar un tipo a `object`

```
int a=1;
object o = a;
```

Esto funciona porque todos los tipos derivan de `Object`, y el unboxing es el acto contrario, es decir de object a tipo

```
object o = 1;
int a = (int)o
```

**Aquí es donde está el problema !!** Veamos un ejemplo

```
float a = 2;
double b = (double)a;
Console.WriteLine(b); // 2
```

Esto funciona sin problema, pero si ahora usamos boxing

```
float a = 2;
object o = a;
double b = (double)o; //ERROR
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Lo único que hicimos es agregar una conversión intermedia, de float a object y de object a double, el sentido común diría que no debería haber problema, pero no es así. La única conversión posible del object es volver a ser lo que era, es decir `float`

**¿Como aplica esto a `IEnumerable.Cast()`?**

Hay que distinguir que existe

- `IEnumerable`
- `IEnumerable<T>`

El primero no tiene tipo (es decir almacena object) y el segundo si lo tiene. La función `Cast` deriva del primero y su implementación es (de forma resumida):

```
//                   IEnumerable sin tipo T ---------------v
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
{
//             v-------OBJECT!!!!
    foreach (object obj in source)
    {
        yield return (TResult)obj;
    }
}
```

Si observas bien, caemos en el mismo problema mencionado anteriormente un `object` que era originalmente float queremos convertirlo en `double`

La solución sería crear nuestra propía función de extension, de esta manera:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static IEnumerable<Tout?> Cast<Tin, Tout>(this IEnumerable<Tin> source) where Tin : INumber<Tin> where Tout : struct
    {
        foreach (Tin obj in source)
        {
            yield return obj as Tout?;
        }
    }
}
```

Y luego llamarla:

```
 var n = numbs.Cast<float,double>().ToList();
```

---

Por otro lado, hay un tema que no quiero dejar pasar, tu dices que

> Me di cuenta de que la función .ToList() es lenta

Si te fijas casi todas las funciones de una lista devuelven un `IEnumerable` (con o sin tipo `<T>`). En la gran mayoría de los casos de uso habituales tu no necesitas pasar a lista usando `.ToList()` deberías poder trabajar el `IEnumerable` directamente.

Si haces la prueba de tiempo sin `.ToList()`

```
var n = numbs.Select(v => (float)v);
clock.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(numbs.Count + ", " + clock.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Vas a ver que se demora cero milisegundos, esto es porque la transformación no se ha aplicado. Y solo se aplica cuando vas a usar el dato. Esto permite concatenar funciones sin perder rendimiento, por ejemplo

```
numbs.Where(v=> v > 100).Select(v => (float)v).OrderBy(v => v);
```

Imagina que si cada función se ejecutara, habría que recorrer la colección 3 veces (una por el Where, otra por el Select y otra por el Orderby). En cambio al ser IEnumerable estas instrucciones se guardan y se ejecutan cuando el dato guardado es requerido.

Al usar el `.ToList()` obligas a ejecutar todas las funciones que tiene la colección, por eso tiene una demora. Solo deberías usar `.ToList()` para casos específicos, como para agregar o eliminar objetos o usar el índice de la colección. El resto de los casos usas el `IEnumerable` directamente

Esto lo menciono porque acá en el sitio he visto repetidas veces que se usa el `.ToList()` de manera indiscriminada y en casos que no es necesario, por ejemplo hacer `.ToList()` para luego hacer un `foreach` ahí recorres la lista 2 veces, pudiendo directamente iterar sobre el `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

Te pasa debido a que el cast no es un convertidor entre tipos, y él (float) es una conversión implícita. Me explico:

Pongamos de ejemplo un caso más sencillo char a string. Sabemos que el string es un array de 1 o más chars.

```
  List<char> chars= new  List<char> { 'a','b','c' };

  var n3 = chars.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

Verás que esto da error. Ya que son a la práctica dos objetos diferentes que no se engloban entre sí, por tanto, requieren conversión y el cast no sirve.
Otro ejemplo cambiando al tipo object que engloba todos los tipos:

```
        List<object> chars= new  List<object> { 'a','b','c' };
        var n3 = chars.Cast<char>().ToList();
```

Verás que en este caso funciona, ya que los datos de dentro siguen siendo chars aunque el sistema entienda que son objects no chars.

En conclusión, volviendo a tu caso, el cast no funciona por el hecho de que los datos que tienes dentro la lista son doubles y no floats.

Básicamente, no son lo mismo porque tienen diferente precisión en los decimales, por lo que requieren conversión.